# How to expand an animated gif without affecting aspect ratio?

Tags: gimp, animation, gif

I am currently trying to turn a 35x75 pixel animated gif into a 75x75 animated gif while preserving the aspect ratio - in other words, I want to add 20 pixels of empty space on either side of the gif. This seems like it should be a simple enough thing to do, in theory, but in practice I've had absolutely no luck.

I tried messing around a bit in GIMP, and it seems like I should be able to copy and paste the animation frames onto a new 75x75 background, but I just can't figure out how to do it - this seems like the most likely method, at the moment. Any help would be greatly appreciated, whether it's in GIMP or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is done with `Image > Canvas size`:

[image]

If there are many frames, you probably want a script to add the background layer to each frame. See `ofn-interleave-layers` [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/gimp-tools/files/scripts/).

PS: before you to anything, make sure the image is de-optimized (`Filters > Animation > Unoptimize`). You can re-optimize it when done.

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what I was looking for.